# How to grab the actual name of the attribute/class within the brackets

Tags: xpath

How do I get the name of the class, in this case it is `84`

```
<div style="width: 50%;" data-test="84" class="test"></div>
```

So I want the contents of the `data-test` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
<div style="width: 50%;" data-test="84" class="test"></div>
```

If you want the value of the `data-test` attribute, you could use:

```
/div/@data-test
```

Or, if you're specifically looking for something with `class` equal to `test`:

```
/div[@class="test"]/@data-test
```

Or, if you want the value of the `data-test` attribute for anything containing a `data-test` attribute:

```
//*[@data-test]/@data-test
```

And if none of these help, you may want to update your question to give us a better idea of what you're looking for.